# Install RV620 Radeon HD 3470 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, amd-graphics

Newbie here - I'm looking for some help on installing the above graphics card on 16.04.

I've updated my system yet the display is only 1024x768.

Could someone please tell me how to install the drivers for this card :)

Comment: There is no need to install a driver. No proprietary driver is available.

Comment: But surely the resolution can't be only 1024x768 can it?

Comment: If you set it to 1024x768 it can or if your monitor only supports 1024x768 it can.

Comment: @devius: I'm afraid that's really not the case, I had the same issue with 16.04 and Samsung 2443BW monitor presented as an `Unknown display` for some time. Then - after a few weeks I guess - it suddenly started to work and changed resolution automatically to 1920x1200. I'm not sure what solved the problem since I wasn't even trying, but it clearly wasn't working "out of the box"